# Keyup not working on custom theme called "Net Seal Theme"

Tags: c#, .net

Today I'm having a problem with the keyup event not working on a custom theme.

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbResolveS2I.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tbResolveS2I_KeyUp);
        tbResolveI2S.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tbResolveI2S_KeyUp);
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void tbResolveS2I_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            btnResolveS2I_Click(sender, e);
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

When I hit enter on my keyboard it sends both textboxes to do the same result. What i mean is if i hit enter on the first textbox it will act like I'm pressing enter on the other textbox aswell

Comment: You say `KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(tbResolveS2I_KeyUp);` twice, is the `KeyUp` your textboxes, and if so why are you using the same name for both?

Comment: @SimonJensen I'm using that twice because i have two textbox's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different events to perform the same thing you could add that code to a method and just call that method from the controls event method.
Also in the theme pack you are using, the button extends from Control and does not have a PerformClick() method.

example:

```
public Main() {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(Main_KeyUp);
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void Main_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
            CustomCode();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }

    private void btnResolveS2I_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CustomCode();
    }

    private void CustomCode() {
        //Perform code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done that, now nothing works when i press enter.

Comment: Can you edit the code preview to include  the changes you've made

Comment: I have edited my answer, I did not see the `KeyPreview`, my apologies.

Comment: Sorry this does not make sense to me. I have multiple textbox's and buttons that each require for me to press enter and it will perform a click.

Comment: in your `tbResolveS2I_KeyUp` event method, you call the button key up event method like this: `btnResolveS2I_Click(sender, e);` instead try using the perform click on the button like this: `btnResolveS2I.PerformClick();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99167/discussion-between-xquantumforcex-and-simon-jensen).